# Chrome - <body onload=""> is not working

Tags: javascript

I know

> "Onload executes when DOM fully loaded.This means it is executed after
>   end of your page. This is useful when you want to do some task when
>   document is fully loaed."

but why these code don't work in chrome(spBodyOnLoadWrapper is a function defined in "init.debug.js" , this function was not  called ):

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" lang="en-us" dir="ltr">
    <head>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/1033/init.debug.js?rev=Cn3X2qRiBI8U52EFeStGwg%3D%3D"></' + 'script>');
     </script>
    </head> 
    <body scroll="no" onload="if (typeof(_spBodyOnLoadWrapper) != 'undefined') _spBodyOnLoadWrapper();" class="v4master">
    </body>
```

These HTML is generated by a Microsoft product named "SharePoint 2010", ugly, and not "best practices" ,  but i have to make it work in chrome...

Comment: Ouch... `document.write` to include a script? seriously? Not even inside `<script>` tags either...

Comment: Looks like there's no reason to use `document.write()`. Why not add a simple `script` tag instead?

Answer (score 5):

`document.write()` is JavaScript code, so it must be included within a `script` element.

Answer (score 2):

I see a few mistakes/bad practices in your HTML:

First of all, you must wrap the `document.write` statement in `script` tags,

Second, using `document.write` is not necessary (and should be considered as a bad practice).
You can simply add the script to your page by placing the `script` tags in `head` or `body`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/1033/init.debug.jsrev=Cn3X2qRiBI8U52EFeStGwg%3D%3D"></script>
```

If you want to specify the script source dynamically, you can create a `script` element, set its source and add it to your document:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var headElement = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
        script = document.createElement('script');
    script.setAttribute('src', '/_layouts/1033/init.debug.jsrev=Cn3X2qRiBI8U52EFeStGwg%3D%3D');
    script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
    headElement.appendChild(script);
</script>
```

Instead of using `onload` attribute, it's better to add an EventListener for `load` event with JavaScript:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    if (typeof(_spBodyOnLoadWrapper) != 'undefined') {
        _spBodyOnLoadWrapper();
    }
});
```

Comment: These HTML is generated by a Microsoft product named "SharePoint 2010", ugly, and not "best practices" , but i have to make it work in chrome...

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest to use the following script:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if(this.readyState == 'complete') {
            if (typeof(_spBodyOnLoadWrapper) != 'undefined') {
                        _spBodyOnLoadWrapper();
                    }
        }
    }
    script.src = '/_layouts/1033/init.debug.js?rev=Cn3X2qRiBI8U52EFeStGwg%3D%3D';
    head.appendChild(script);
}
```

The usage of document.write is not a good idea. The code above dynamically adds a new script tag into the header of the current page. It detects when this script is loaded and executes your function.

Comment: I didn't down-vote, but: Wjat is `helper` supposed to be... and how is the `body.onload` event supposed to fire, if the script isn't added until _after_ the window.onload event fires?

Comment: That's the idea. You don't need to use bodu.onload at all. Window.onload and later .onreadystatechange are the things which you need. However, as far as I can see the other people here like the answer below.

Comment: If you use the code with onload inside the body tag you will probably need another js function, because later you may want to add another library. Also, I found that having script in html tags is not the most elegant solution.

Comment: I never go for in-html-js, don't get me wrong... I fully understand your code, but I'm not sure if _you_ do. it feels like a blind copy-paste, mainly because you don't explain anything, and left this line in: `script.onload = helper;`, which, with your code as it stands, won't work (helper is undefined)

Comment: :) I forgot to remove it. Of course it is copy-paste from somewhere, but it is a code that I used a lot in my projects and I know what it does :). I disagree that I didn't explain what is the purpose of it. Just check the text below the snippet. Isn't it enough?

Comment: It isn't, I'm afraid. The OP might expect this to work with the `<body onload>` attribute, but seeing as the script isn't added 'till after the `window.onload` event, it _won't work_.

Comment: Having document.write just like that in the code is a bad practice. You should have an entry point of your code. Otherwise, sooner or later you may end up with a messy codebase. window.onload is such a place. After that, loading external js files is made with adding new script tags and listening for onreadystatechange event allow us to make a chain of imports.

Comment: Yes, it depends of the context. But I guess that @Raymond needs to execute some things, not when the body tag is ready, but the page is fully loaded. That's my impression based on his question (the first few lines). Anyway I agree with you that my solution may not be perfect at this case.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I know all this (seriously, silver JS badge in less than a year). you _should_ explain all this in the answer, so the OP sees it, not to me. I commented on this question, before there were any answers, saying that document.write is not a good idea... inform the OP, not those who already are informed

Comment: Note taken. Thanks. (By the way what you mean by *OP*)

Comment: OP = Original Poster. PS, I don't mean to come across as arrogant as I may have done.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the script tags in the head without `document.write`. Secondly, I suggest you put the code which you want to execute in a separate function as well in your head section but anywho, below example might work as well (see also [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/#/aFIzuJo/1/edit)):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" lang="en-us" dir="ltr">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/1033/init.debug.js?rev=Cn3X2qRiBI8U52EFeStGwg%3D%3D"></script>
</head>

  <body scroll="no" onload="javascript:if (typeof(_spBodyOnLoadWrapper) != 'undefined'){ _spBodyOnLoadWrapper();}" class="v4master">
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem and tried the solutions suggested here but they didn’t work. Some more searching indicates that this is a bug in Chrome that appears to go back at least to 2009:

http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/7VIpByhmU3U

The issue is that body.onload (and also window.onload) are firing *before* the web page has completely loaded, apparently in my case because I’m loading large images whose time-to-load varies with net traffic. The work around is to put your JavaScript into the page *after* any referenced HTML, but before the  end tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     if (typeof(_spBodyOnLoadWrapper) != 'undefined') _spBodyOnLoadWrapper();
</script>
```

This also had the effect for me of producing a substantially more immediate update of the page content in the other browsers (Firefox, Safari) where the bug doesn’t occur.

Answer (score 0):

check if you have 2 onload events.