# Html body "onload" is not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, servlets

I have written sample web application with servlets and jsp. As per the below code the action url should be executed automatically
according to the "onload". I have written this below code in one of my servlet, The below "onload" form hits the path in action
only in Firefox and IE but not in Chrome(41.0.2272.74 beta-m (64-bit)).I have seen the link [Chrome -  is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18459305/chrome-body-onload-is-not-working)  but i did not get proper idea, I have my below code in the end of servelt. there is nothing to execute after this code in the servlet.

```
 out.write("<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd\"> \n");
    out.write("<html><body onload=\"alert('alert has been fired');document.forms[0].submit()\">\n");
    out.write("<form method=\"POST\" action=\"" + actionUrl + "\">\n");
    out.write("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"resourcePath\" value=\"" + callbackUrl + "\"/>\n");
    out.write("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"locale\" value=\"" + locale + "\"/>\n");
    out.write("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"rspjRequest\" value=\"" + true + "\"/>\n");
    out.write("</form>\n</body>\n</html>\n");
    out.close();
```

Is there any reserved key words of chrome in the above action url?

Comment: Any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: It works for me in Chrome 41.0.2272.89 (64-bit)

Comment: no errors in the console but it does not redirected to action url.

Comment: I think why people are down voted for this.

Comment: If you change to `onload="alert('running'); document.forms[0].submit()"` do you get the alert?

Comment: it is not considering the alert even after adding to the onload like you shown

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72834/discussion-between-m-s-naidu-and-barmar).

Comment: hello @Barmar, Please look into my above edited code. If i execute this code in the html format, it is working in chrome. but if it is from servlet, alert() is not running.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with how servlets run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation finally i got solution for my problem. I forgot to set the Content type for the response in the servlet.

**response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");**

Chrome browser will display response in the form of html page by using above line.

Answer (score 0):

You can try function in script tag of that html page.

```
  <script>
     function myfunction() {
     alert("This is the first.");
    }

    window.onload = function()
    {
     myfunction;
    }
  </script>
```

Comment: This code is also not working when i insert in my servlet code