# HTTP POST auto submit in Chrome

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, http

I'm trying to write a HttpModule in C# that generates an empty POST request to a certain URL.  I have used the following code that I got from another post:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("<html>");
sb.AppendFormat(@"<body onload='document.forms[""form""].submit()'>");
sb.AppendFormat("<form name='form' action='{0}' method='post'>", HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString());
sb.AppendFormat("<input value='submit' type='submit'/>");
//sb.AppendFormat("<input type='hidden' name='id' value='{0}'>", 1);
// Other params go here
sb.Append("</form>");
sb.Append("</body>");
sb.Append("</html>");

HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(sb.ToString());

HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

In IE, this works fine.  However, in Chrome, I just see the generated markup, almost like the body onload isn't firing correctly.  What am I missing?

Comment: Additionally, I noticed that document.forms is empty on the page.  That probably has something to do with why the form itself isn't submitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting this value

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
```

As per this answer [Html body "onload" is not working in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29003605/html-body-onload-is-not-working-in-chrome)

Comment: I had to modify it a bit, but that seemed to do the trick.  Here is what I used:

    `HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/html; charset=UTF-8";`

Thanks for your help!